# How can I make SourceAFIS work on Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ubuntu, mono

I am trying to use SourceAFIS 1.7.0 on Ubuntu with mono and get a few error.

1.

> $ mono DatabaseAnalyzer.exe
>
> Scanning folder TestDatabase
>
> Running extractor benchmark
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
>
> File name: 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>
> at DatabaseAnalyzer.DatabaseAnalyzer.RunExtractorBenchmark ()
>   <0x40674790
>   + 0x00033> in :0      at DatabaseAnalyzer.DatabaseAnalyzer.RunMatcherBenchmark () <0x40674600 +
>   0x000eb> in :0
>
> at DatabaseAnalyzer.DatabaseAnalyzer.Run () <0x40642a40 + 0x000bf> in
>   :0
>
> at DatabaseAnalyzer.DatabaseAnalyzer.Main (System.String[] args)
>   <0x4063bd50 + 0x00037> in :0
>
> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>
> File name: 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'     at
>   DatabaseAnalyzer.DatabaseAnalyzer.RunExtractorBenchmark () <0x40674790
>   + 0x00033> in :0      at DatabaseAnalyzer.DatabaseAnalyzer.RunMatcherBenchmark () <0x40674600 +
>   0x000eb> in :0
>
> at DatabaseAnalyzer.DatabaseAnalyzer.Run () <0x40642a40 + 0x000bf> in
>   :0
>
> at DatabaseAnalyzer.DatabaseAnalyzer.Main (System.String[] args)
>   <0x4063bd50 + 0x00037> in :0

According to https://sourceforge.net/p/sourceafis/discussion/1051112/thread/dd8df289/#a006, WinForms should be applied here instead of WPF and use bitmap class to replace the bitmapimage class of WPF, but I don't know how to do it exactly. Does anybody have such experience?

This is the original function used WPF bitmap class

```js
  static MyPerson Enroll(string filename, string name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enrolling {0}...", name);

            // Initialize empty fingerprint object and set properties
            MyFingerprint fp = new MyFingerprint();
            fp.Filename = filename;
            // Load image from the file
            Console.WriteLine(" Loading image from {0}...", filename);
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            fp.AsBitmapSource = image;
            // Above update of fp.AsBitmapSource initialized also raw image in fp.Image
            // Check raw image dimensions, Y axis is first, X axis is second
            Console.WriteLine(" Image size = {0} x {1} (width x height)", fp.Image.GetLength(1), fp.Image.GetLength(0));

            // Initialize empty person object and set its properties
            MyPerson person = new MyPerson();
            person.Name = name;
            // Add fingerprint to the person
            person.Fingerprints.Add(fp);

            // Execute extraction in order to initialize fp.Template
            Console.WriteLine(" Extracting template...");
            Afis.Extract(person);
            // Check template size
            Console.WriteLine(" Template size = {0} bytes", fp.Template.Length);

            return person;
        }
```

2. > $ mono SourceAFIS.FingerprintAnalysis.exe
   >   The entry point method could not be loaded

How can I fix this with a more meaningful exception?

Comment: what version of mono and what distro and version is this?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu15.10  64bit and mono 4.4.0

Comment: how did you install mono?

Comment: With the instruction on Mono website [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives)

Answer (score 1):

> WinForms should be applied here instead of WPF and use bitmap class to
>   replace the bitmapimage class of WPF, but I don't know how to do it
>   exactly. Does anybody have such experience?

Do you know how to program in C# language? What they mean in that forum is that you need to change the code to not use the WPF library, but Windows Forms UI toolkit.

If you get exceptions trying to load "PresentationCore" at runtime, it means it's still trying to load WPF.

Comment: I tried to change 'using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;' into 'using System.drawing' or 'using System.Windows.Forms' in the code. The problem is I don't know how to change WPF-based class into Winfoms-based.

Comment: then you need to study about those UI toolkits APIs, I would recommend to create some sample programs with them, it will take you just some weeks to do, very easy

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `mono-complete` package, e.g.

```
apt-get install mono-complete
```

<sup>Related: [Mono, failing to open executable](https://askubuntu.com/q/50735/78223).</sup>

Also make sure you've [*.NET Framework*](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download) installed, e.g. by using `winetricks`:

```
apt-get install winetricks
winetricks dotnet46
```

See: [Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationCore'](https://forums.asp.net/t/1694533.aspx).

> PresentationCore is .NET 4

---

Further more, you can try the following [suggestions](https://forums.asp.net/t/1694533.aspx):

- In *IIS* try to *Enable 32-Bit Applications* in the Application Pools's Advanced Settings
- Configure authentication as follow:

  - Disable Anonymous Authentication.
  - Enable ASP.NET Impersonation.
  - Enable Windows Authentication.